# Installing nginx on ubuntu 18.04 gives 502 Connection timed out error

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, server

I followed all the steps to install nginx on ubuntu 18.04 given in [this website,](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) but i am unable to see the default Nginx landing page: Welcome to nginx! which is given on this website.

I am using AWS EC2 Service and my server IPv4 Public IP is
13.59.36.38

I used the following commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nginx
sudo ufw app list
sudo ufw allow 'Nginx HTTP'
sudo ufw status
systemctl status nginx
```

After that i typed http://13.59.36.38/ in my browser but i got output: Connection timed out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely, your EC2 instance was launched into a VPC.  You need to change the Security Group for that VPC to allow http traffic over port 80.

Use the AWS console and to change the Security Group for your VPC.  Add an inbound rule on port 80 from the source address 0.0.0.0/0.

Refer to [this AWS guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#WorkingWithSecurityGroups).  Scroll to the section titled **To add a rule using the console** and follow these steps:

> Open the Amazon VPC console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/.
>
> In the navigation pane, choose Security Groups.
>
> Select the security group to update. The details pane displays the details for the > security group, plus tabs for working with its inbound rules and outbound rules.
>
> On the Inbound Rules tab, choose Edit. Select an option for a rule for inbound traffic > for Type, and then fill in the required information. For example, for a public web > server, choose HTTP or HTTPS and specify a value for Source as 0.0.0.0/0.
>
> Note
>
> If you use 0.0.0.0/0, you enable all IPv4 addresses to access your instance using HTTP > or HTTPS. To restrict access, enter a specific IP address or range of addresses.
>
> Optionally provide a description for the rule, and choose Save.
>
> You can also allow communication between all instances associated with this security > > group. On the Inbound Rules tab, choose All Traffic from the Type list. Start typing > > the ID of the security group for Source; this provides you with a list of security > groups. Select the security group from the list and choose Save.
>
> If you need to, you can use the Outbound Rules tab to add rules for outbound traffic.

Comment: thanks, now its working after adding a security group.